# Difference between @click="$emit("myFunction")" and @click="emitFunction"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

Is there any difference between two of them? And which one is best practice?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference between them, both of them do the same thing, they emit an event to the parent component.

As for which one is the best practice, I would say the second one, because it is more customisable, looks simpler, and if you name your function better, like `emitFormSubmitted`, or something similar it reads way more easier.

Also the second option leaves possibility to do some actions before emitting, like checking validity, changing state, etc.

Comment: Both are fine, adding methods just to add methods will eventually make your code unreadable. If you need to add more functionality you can just refactor to a method. Straight forward > Abstraction imo ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I agree, using simplest javascript at template is better.